# Google Maps - User Interface with Groups of Markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to setup a custom Google Map on a project I'm working on. Setting up the map itself and styling it isn't a problem - the interactivity is where I need some advice please;

The map will have one central location/marker (always visible). In addition, there will be 2 "groups" of markers which can be visually shown/hidden by the user. These groups will contain sub-groups of markers e.g;

Group 1 = Local Businesses: Corporate, Restaurants & Bars, etc.

Group 2 = Transport: Rail, Underground, etc.

The user can show/hide the two groups (e.g. hiding Group 1 will hide all corporate and restaurant markers). They can also hide individual "child" groups of markers e.g. hide Underground markers.

The site is already using WordPress and jQuery, so if there is already a plugin for either platform which already does this - that would be great!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goMap (http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/)  was the solution, along with this great article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690045/How-to-Display-and-Hide-Marker-Groups-in-Google-Ma